# Proving a function is bounded above.

Tags: analysis, derivatives, continuity

[image]

Hi all, while doing this question ,I feel that I understand the concept of the question, but can't seem to formulate it into a viable answer.
If the limit as $x \rightarrow \infty$ is the same as $x \rightarrow -\infty$ and equals zero, just by thinking about the graph ,it is clear that there must be a maximum or minimum.
Does the first condition imply the function is bounded?
Any advice on answering this question would be much appreciated

Comment: Yes, the first condition implies boundedness. You can find constants $d,c>0$ s.t. $|f(x)|<d$ if $x\notin [-c,c]$. next to that $f[-c,c]$ is compact as image of a compact set under a continuous function, hence bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick some $\epsilon>0$ (for example $\epsilon=1$, why not). From $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$ we conclude that there exists some $b\in\mathbb R$ such that $f(x)<\epsilon$ for all $x>b$. Similarly, there exists $a\in\mathbb R$ such that $f(x)<\epsilon$ for $x<a$ because $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=0$. If $a\ge b$, this shows $\epsilon$ is an upper bound for $f$. And if $a<b$, the continuous function $f$ is bounded on the compact interval $[a,b]$, say $f(x)<M$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Then $\max\{\epsilon,M\}$ is an upper bound for $f$.

Now use condition $(ii)$. Since $f(c)>0$ we can take $\epsilon=\frac12f(c)$ in the argument above. Then any upper bound we find must be $\ge f(c)$, which implies that $a<b$ and $M\ge f(c)$. The maximum of $f|_{[a,b]}$ is attained at some $x_0\in[a,b]$. As this is a global maximum of $f$, it must also be a local maximum, hence $f'(x_0)=0$.